# Rail 6 app, navigating to link is taking me to blank page and only re-direct if you refersh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

All, i am facing an issue with routing when i click on the link i am taking to a blank page and only when i click refersh in my browser am i taking to the re-directed page.

In my Navbar App:
[image]

```
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item"  %>
              
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, class: "dropdown-item"   %>
```

Routes
devise_for :users

If i click on login i am taking to a blank page

[image]

If i hard refresh (F5) I am redirected. This i am using devise Gem

[image]

Any pointers will be helpful.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Strange. Please remove class: 'dropdown-item', maybe bootstrap interferes with it. If not. check your Network tab in the browser console and see what request it does.

Comment: Do you have turbolinks enabled?

Comment: I've had this issue in the past with Turbolinks, can you try adding this to the `sessions/new` view and see if it works?

`<% content_for :head do %>
  <meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload" />
<% end %>`

You'll also need to add `yield(:head)` to your layout file before the end of `</head>`.

Comment: The first page seems not to be empty. It displays the text  "2021".

Comment: I have tried this but this didn't work. The problem i found out is that because its custom boostrap, i had my partial header and footer and the html on the page itself reference footer and other had header, hence it just redirect with 2021 but i had to refresh to be routed to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't redirected after you hit refresh. Devise routes work fine because you land on the correct URL `users\sign_in` after you click the login link. So the reason your page is not loading is not Devise but something on the login page that prevents it from rendering. Opening the browser console and checking for JS errors might give you some hints.

Comment: i do see this warningThe resource https://demoproject-randi2160920490.codeanyapp.com/assets/application.debug-9e0f6944a9ad6740ae459231ca3193aa78b69acfadaafaba30023b6e8169f7ba.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: @Randymangal You are working with a custom bootstrap template and copying the HTML from the template and paste it into your existing pages together with head and body sections. Look at your HTML structure, you have a soup of multiple `head` and `body` sections. You are supposed to have one for each. Rework your page structure so that it has the correct HTML structure and only loads the assets that you need. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: Great Pointer, it was because i do have more than one footer and body within the page and the Application html.erb file Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. For my project I used some bootstrap template and it had this js code in the footer:

```
<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
```

Every time I click a turbo link, the content of page was replaced with a current year - 2022. (2021 in your case)